# Taylor expansion in Logistic regression

Tags: notation, taylor-expansion

More of a question about notation of the Taylor expansion in Logistic regression that anything else.

Given a nonlinear cost function 
$
J(\theta)= - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i (b+x_iw) - ln(1+e^{(b+x_iw)})
$
and given a Taylor expansion to approximate the cost function
$
f(\theta) \approx f(\theta^{(t)})+f^{\prime}(\theta^{(t)}) (\theta^{(t+1)}-\theta^{(t)})
$.
What I want to know is if the constant term is supposed to be a derivative of the cost function 
$
f(\theta) = \frac{d}{d\theta} J(\theta) = J^{\prime}(\theta)
$
or is the constant term just equal to the cost function
$
f(\theta) =J(\theta)
$

I found differing information [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TuttBDdbls8&t=10m11s) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for Taylor expansion series, the constant term should be close to the value you are trying to approximate.

Therefore, if you are trying to approximate $J(\theta^{(t+1)})$, then the first term of your expansion should take a known value of $J$, such as the $J(\theta^{(t)})$.

If you are trying to approximate $J'(\theta^{(t+1)})$, then the first term should be $J'(\theta^{(t)})$.

Comment: Right for for the case of logistic regression then I guess the constant term $f(\theta) =J(\theta)$. It would be useful if they used a different notation instead of defining $f(x)$ twice. For example something like $T(\theta) \approx J(\theta^{(t)})+J^{\prime}(\theta^{(t)}) (\theta^{(t+1)}-\theta^{(t)})$

Comment: I understand your confusion. Did I answer your question?

Comment: Leaving the general case aside, can you confirm if $f(\theta) = J(\theta)$ in the specific case of logistic regression?

Comment: To the best of my understanding, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://dinh-hung-tu.github.io/gradient-descent-vs-newton-method/)

Depending on the context, Newton's method can mean one of the two below:

- In calculus, Newton's method for root finding is a root-finding algorithm which produces successively better approximations to the roots (or zeroes) of a real-valued function.
- In optimization, Newton's method for optimisation is applied to the derivative f ′ of a twice-differentiable function f to find the roots of the derivative (solutions to f ′ (x) = 0), also known as the stationary points of f. These solutions may be minima, maxima, or saddle points.